# Мониторинг ресурса

Tags: администрирование, сервер, логирование

Подскажите, как настроить мониторинг сервера, а именно метрики базы данных и сайта (сколько запросов в секунду и т.п.), метрики сервера (CPU, RAM и др.).

Comment: awstats (статистика апача), munin или zabbix (статистика и графики нагрузки, zabbix ещё и мониторинг)

Answer (score 1):

1. tcpdump - покажет подробный трафик на интерфейсе, откуда, куда и какой пакет идёт. По его данным можно будет оценить активность нагрузки
2. netstat -a  покажет какие соединения уже установлены
3. top (если сервер юниксовый)

Ну а если конкретнее надо, то давайте информацию о том, какой сервер, какая ось, какие сервисы подняты

Comment: я никогда не интересовался нагрузкой на систему, когда поднимал сйты макс. моя посещаемость было около 10 000 - 11 000 человек в день, но никогда за всю свою жизнь не сталкивался с проблемами нагрузки. Сейчас мы будем запускать новый ресурс и хотелось бы последить за активностью и нагрузкой. По ос. сказать не могу, хостера еще не выбрали, но могу сказать это будет что-то из юниксов.

Comment: ну пока всё равно маловато информации, хотелось бы знать, что за сервер (характеристики, виртуальный/выделенный), что за ось на нём, какие сервисы ещё есть (базы данных, почтовый...) Можно с скайп: danildan75work

Answer (score 1):

NewRelic - платно и вкусно. Zabbix - бесплатно, но кажется overkill для ваших нужд.Модные нынче StatsD, Graphite и Logstash имеют массу примеров в сети для мониторинга web-стэка: от нагрузки на DB, до посещаемости отдельных URL на основании логов.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё на хостинге можно посмотреть, если конечно это там есть!

Answer (score 1):

Из того, чем пользовался:

1. Graphite  + Grafana - идеальное решение, если надо мониторить всего 1 машину. Я даже [докер контейнер](https://hub.docker.com/r/suvitruf/grafana_graphite/) делал для этого. Установка в 1 клик. Если нужен кластер, то есть [карбонат](https://github.com/jssjr/carbonate).
2. Zabbix хорош, много всего есть, но сложен в настройке.
3. Сейчас у нас в парке куча машин, устанавливать и мониторить на конкретной тачке сложно. Перешли на [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/). Он платный, да. Но зато всё в одном местер. Куча готовых интеграций: мониторнг супервизорда, консула, Java, kubernetes, nginx и кучи других ваших сервисов.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю в перечисленные сервисы еще [Sensu](https://sensuapp.org/) и [Prometheus](http://prometheus.io/). Пользовался пока только первым, он требует некоторое время для вхождения, но после этого очень прост в работе и практически ничего не жрет (хотя выбор редиса в качестве хранилища данных выглядит немного странно).

Также не могу не порекомендовать [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) - в отличие от вышеприведенных приложений, задача graylog - собирать логи, однако в остальном он очень похож, вплоть до алертов при превышении заданных параметров. В качестве бэкенда используется ElasticSearch, который позволяет легко найти что угодно в потоках данных.

Все перечисленное ПО распространяется как OSS и доступно на Docker Hub.